# Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler

Tags: gcc, gnu

In OSX during C++ program compilation with `g++` I use

```
LD_FLAGS= -Wl,-stack_size,0x100000000
```

but in SUSE Linux I constantly get errors like:

```
x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--stack'
```

and similar.

I know that it is possible to use

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

but this is not nice as not always can a single user do that.

How can I increase the stack size in Linux with GCC for a single application?

Comment: if it helps:

2.6.18.8-0.9-default #1 SMP Sun Feb 10 22:48:05 UTC 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: gcc --ver:

gcc version 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (SUSE Linux)

Comment: Attempting to set `rlimit_stack` after [Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) remediations may result in failure or related problems. Also see Red Hat [Issue 1463241](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1463241)

Comment: `ld -v`, please

Answer (score 82):

You can set the stack size programmatically with [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit), e.g.

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const rlim_t kStackSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;   // min stack size = 16 MB
    struct rlimit rl;
    int result;

    result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        if (rl.rlim_cur < kStackSize)
        {
            rl.rlim_cur = kStackSize;
            result = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "setrlimit returned result = %d\n", result);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Note: even when using this method to increase stack size you should not declare large local variables in `main()` itself, since you may well get a stack overflow as soon as you enter `main()`, before the `getrlimit`/`setrlimit` code has had a chance to change the stack size. Any large local variables should therefore be defined only in functions which are subsequently called from `main()`, after the stack size has successfully been increased.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct `#include` s for your OS, e.g. for Mac OS X it would be `#include <sys/resource.h>`.

Comment: I tried it on SLES 11. Even the value is set I cannot define a local variable according to the new limit --> `segmentation fault`. Only when I run in the command line `ulimit -s 16000` then I can define a local variable like `char x [14000000]`. Apparently the stack size is not set through this code. Any idea?

Comment: @AlBundy: all I can tell you is that the above code works for me on both OS X and various flavours of Linux. One thought occurs to me though: are you trying to declare a large local variable in `main()` itself ? That won't work of course, because you'll get a stack overflow before you even get to the `getrlimit`/`setrlimit` code. Put the large local variable in another function and then call this function from `main` (after the `getrlimit`/`setrlimit` code).

Comment: @PaulR: OK. I tried it in `main()` but __after__ I set the new limit. Apparently this does not work. When I call from `main()` a function which has a huge local variable then it works. I checked it now with different limits and all works perfectly. Conclusion: The stack limit must be set in `main()` in order to be active for the rest of the program. I had also to close the `ssh` session because I was playing around with `ulimit -s`and I got always -1 as return code.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that - I've added a note to the answer now in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: @PaulR: The documentation says: "_The maximum size of the process stack, in bytes_". This means all threads are sharing the stack and when my program has up to 200 threads I have to increase the stack size with the method and then all should be OK?

Comment: @AlBundy: each thread will still get the default stack size for a thread (although you can easily change this of course), but by increasing the process stack size you'll be able to create more threads, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75086/discussion-between-al-bundy-and-paul-r).

Comment: This just causes my program to freeze.

Answer (score 25):

Instead of `stack_size`, use `--stack` like so:

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,4194304 -o program program.c
```

This example should give you 4 MB of stack space. Works on MinGW's GCC, but as the manpage says, "This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker" (i.e. only works for outputting Windows binaries). Seems like there isn't an option for ELF binaries.

Comment: unfortunately I tried this and it does not work:

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--stack'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Yes, edited my answer as I noticed that it doesn't work for ELF output. Sorry I'm not of much help here.

Comment: In CMake, there are [a few commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989674) that set this option, which all work for me on Windows.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old topic, but none of the flags answered here worked for me. Anyway by I found out that `-Wl,-z,stack-size=4194304` (example for 4MB) seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

Consider using `-fsplit-stack` option https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks

Comment: `-fsplit-stack` decreased performance by ~20% for my use case.

Comment: Hi @Dennis, consider comparing this performance to use of heap.

Answer (score 2):

Change it with the ulimit bash builtin, or setrlimit(), or at login
with PAM (pam_limits.so).

It's a settable
user resource limit; see RLIMIT_STACK in setrlimit(2).

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/221976-enlarge-stack-size-gcc

Comment: as I said, I can not do that

I have also to give this app to another users, who should not use this trick

Comment: You don't understand: the call to `setrlimit` can be done inside your C++ code, at the start of `main`.