# Const char declaration causes stack overflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, constants, stack-overflow, cppunit

In my VC++ CPPUNIT project the following code in a unit test causes a stack overflow exception:

```
const int n = 1000000;
const char *test[n];
```

> First-chance exception at 0x00AD89E7 in Utilities_Tests.exe:
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00132000).
>   Unhandled exception at 0x00AD89E7 in Utilities_Tests.exe: 0xC00000FD:
>   Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00132000).

But this does not:

```
const int n = 1000000;
char test[n];
```

The stack overflow happens before the code is executed, thus a breakpoint at the top of the unit test will not be hit. Any idea why this happens? I have the workaround but I'm just curious what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `char` is 1 byte, a `char*` is, most likely, 4 bytes (can be more, can be less).

So the first case attempts to allocate more memory (~4 times more) an the stack. Stack memory is limited, it just happens that `1000000` bytes fit on your platform on the stack, but `4 * 1000000` don't.

Answer (score 3):

On 32-bit computers pointers are four bytes, so one million pointers are four million bytes (on 64-bit machines the size of a pointer is 64 bit, so eight million bytes for your array). Stacks are normally in the range one to four megabytes, so you `char` array (one million bytes) fits on the stack but the pointer array does not.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are running out of stack space. Stack space is a finite per-thread resource; making nested function calls and using local variables consumes it. When you run out, a stack overflow occurs.

Your first example allocates a million `char*`, which typically would be either 4MB or 8MB of memory. Your second example allocates only 1MB. A typical size for allocated stack space is also around 1MB, so the results are not altogether surprising.

For possible solutions see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).