# Increase stack size for a program to run

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to increase the stack size, for my program to run, the reason is that I've a recursive call causing a stack overflow. Is there anyway I can change the default stack size?

Comment: Maybe if you tell us the compiler?

Comment: see this solution?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com

Comment: You can on most platforms, but I predict it won't solve your problem. If you overflow the stack, you either have unlimited recursion or at least use asymptotically too much stack space, so even if you increase the stack size, you can only run your program slightly longer/on slightly larger data sets. Better fix your algorithm instead.

Comment: @delnan: I guess it depends... AIX 32bits allocates 96kb for the stack of each thread created with `pthread_create`. It is not that hard to push beyond 96k...

Comment: better suggestion as above - to fix the algorithm. However, the other part is, that the "stack" size of the system would need to be increased and is not specific to the program. The increased stack size allowed on the system then would allow the program to execute (if the code is really blocked by the stack size limitations). For that @jman answer below suffices for setting and validating.

Answer (score 2):

If its a *NIX, use

```
ulimit -s <number_in_kb>
```

You'd set that in your environment before running your program. You can also set it programatically as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284691/417980).

You can view the current value by running `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 1):

Use editbin to change the stack size of the program:

EDITBIN.EXE /STACK: yourprogram.exe

Comment: And what if he uses Linux?

Comment: @H2CO3: then he does not have this problem.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Like any sane system, Linux limits the stack size too.

Comment: @delnan: It does, however not by changing the binary in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Its compiler dependent. In Visual studio stacksize is fixed to 1 MB.
You can increase it using /STACK linker option.