# malloc() returning a null pointer

Tags: c, malloc

I'm attempting a C programming assignment where I need to iterate through each index of each line of a document, and set an integer value at each character index in a corresponding array ar:

```
//Jagged array ar containing pointers to each row
int* ar[line_count];
//The size of each row is the line width * the size of an int ptr
const int line_size = max_width * sizeof(int*);

//For each line
for (i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
{
    //If the first runthrough, copy the blank array 
    if (i == 0)
    {
        ar[i] = malloc(line_size);
        memcpy(ar[i], blank_ar, line_size);
    }
    //Otherwise, copy from the last row
    else
    {
        ar[i] = malloc(line_size);
        //This is set to a null pointer after several runthroughs
        memcpy(ar[i], ar[i - 1], line_size);
    }
    //Edit the current row ar[i]
}
```

The only problem is, after some 9 iterations, malloc starts returning a null pointer that causes memcpy to (obviously) not work.

Is there any reason this is happening? There is no way I'm running out of memory as I only allocate these tiny arrays 9 times.

Comment: What does your debugger say? Any 0-values inbetween?

Comment: What have you assigned as the value of max_width? Check for some trivial mistakes you have done.

Comment: Forget about it.. What does `errno` say?

Comment: How did you observed the null return from malloc? Using a debugger? by the program crashing? etc..

Comment: When you say "starts returning," do you mean every subsequent call to `malloc` also returns a null pointer?

Comment: Yes every subsequent call returns null.

Comment: And I can see the null return via a debugger. I know it's happening

Comment: is `line_count` a compile time constant (macro, enum) or a variable? It looks to me that `ar` is a VLA, which probably is not a good idea, since you might smash your "stack".

Comment: line_count is a variable, but the array is not variable length in the sense that I never realloc() it larger. How could that destroy the stack?

Comment: a variable length array is an array whose declared size cannot be calculated at compile time. If `line_count` is a variable whose value is not known at compile time, then `int *ar[line_count]` is definitely a VLA.

Comment: So variable length arrays are a bad idea? What do you recommend instead of using them then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`malloc` will return the null pointer when it fails. Some obvious reasons why this could happen:

- You have exhausted heap memory. That is plausible if `line_size` is very large.
- You have corrupted the heap. That could happen if there are errors in the code that you are running, but have removed for the purpose of asking this question.

Inspect the value of `errno` to find out more information about the failure.

Comment: How do I do this? Is it part of stderr?

Comment: Use `strerror()` to get a text representation of what the error represented by `errno`. Or simpler call `perror()` to print it to the console. Like this: `perror("malloc failed");`

Comment: Okay I did that and it returned 'malloc failed: Not enough space'. The problem is, if I pause the app just before it crashes, I'm only using some 484kb of memory, and have hundreds of mb of memory remaining, according to task manager. Eclipse also says that it crashed because of a segmentation fault.

Comment: What does `max_width` equal? Is the code fine if you run the version in the quesiton. In other words, with lots of the actual program's functionality commented out.

Comment: Max width is 100, so I'm really not allocating much. I don't think I can run the code in isolation unfortunately, can you give me any idea of the sort of thing that might corrupt the heap?

Comment: Writing to memory that you have not allocated may corrupt the heap. Since you did not show the code that you are running, it's not really fair to continue this. What's more, I'm sure I answered the question you asked which was of a general nature.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you stack is too little, try to modify the default stack at compile/linking time in your IDE. If you are using GCC take a look into this [Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com)

Comment: Stack size does not affect `malloc` (at least, it shouldn't).