# How to create a C++ bool 2D array with size 40,000?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, matrix

I want to make a bool matrix named `connectionsOf` with size of up to 40 000. Here is my code:

```
int index = 40000;
bool connectionsOf[index][index];
```

However, when I run it on a file with 37 000 numbers to fill up the matrix, there is a segmentation fault.
Browswing around on stackoverflow, I discovered it's because the index number is too high that it blows the stack.
Is there a way to make this stack possible though? such as static, const, dynamic, pointers? and if so, what should I replace my code with?

Comment: Thats not an array of size 40000; its (40000*40000) or **1600000000**. Just a wee bit over your likely stack limit (and this won't compile in C++ anyway, as it is effectively a VLA).

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think it will compile with GCC, as a GNU extension.

Comment: you need to dynamic allocate the memory, but why you need that huge number, can't you process in chunks?

Comment: or you can use as a int vector with bit shift, so in every int you can store 8 bool and with var &0x00000001 you can check the bit

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate a two-dimensional bit array (and likely save a bit of memory) by writing a wrapper around [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

```
class BitMatrix
{
public:
    BitMatrix (int size) : size_(size), bits_(size_ * size_) {}
    void set(int x, int y) { bits_.set(y * size_ + x); }
    bool test(int x, int y) { return bits_.test(y * size_ + x); }
private:
    int size_;
    boost::dynamic_bitset bits_;
};
```

If you know the size at compile time, you can also use this technique with [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: There's a _specialization_ of `std::vector<bool>` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) which implements the "dynamically-sized bitset". It can be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question depends on compiler you are using.
For gcc see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com).
But why do you need to allocate such large data massif on stack, not on heap?
And, by the way, you need to allocate 200 x 200 array to get 40 000 items (200^2).

Comment: to clarify, it needs to be 40,000x40,000. I use g++.

Comment: Ok, when your code is correct. So, did you see my link? it should work for `g++`.

Answer (score 2):

you're abusing stack. 40'000 x 40'000 x sizeof(bool) = (at least) 800'000'000. that's a lot (800MB in a single chunk)

try:

```
index = 40000;
bool** connections = new bool*[index];
for (int t = 0; t < index; ++t) {
    connections[t] = new bool[index];
}
```

be sure to dispose of it adequately, too (the same as above, just reverse - first iterate and dispose array elements, then dispose table itself)

Comment: it's a 2D array, not 1D.. I'm not quite sure what you mean by disposing/when since I need to access the matrix during run-time with user input.

Comment: This code makes an array-of-arrays.  "Dispose" here means that everything allocated by `new []` must be deallocated by `delete []`.  You have to delete the inner arrays first before deleting the outer array.

Comment: why do people repeat the nonsense of "beeellions of `new` calls" for "2D arrays" over and over ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the stack size via compiler flags.

Comment: how does one go about doing this? since my program will be tested on a computer different then mine, is there a way to do this from my files?