# increase stack size to 20 gb giving integer overflow error

Tags: linux, memory, c, stack

I need to run a C program which will use around `20Gb` of RAM while executing. I took help from [Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com).

I am trying to expand stack size on Linux using `setrlimit`. But when I try to assign `20*1024*1024*1024` to `rlim_cur`, the compiler

`warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]`

How do I expand the stack?

Comment: Maybe try using the heap instead? The problem is most likely that you can't store 20*1024*1024*1024 into rlim_cur as it is only an integer. The number you are trying to store is 35 bits long, so you can't store it in the 32 bit integer.

Comment: If rlim_cur is a 32-bit int, you may be on a 32-bit platform and won't be able to address more than 4GB anyway. What does the `arch` command say?

Answer (score 0):

The calculations `20*1024*1024*1024` are performed on `int` constants; the result has `int` type. On your x86_64 platform, `int` is not enough to represent large numbers (greater than 2<sup>31</sup>) - that's what the compiler says.

To do it right, use a type that has 64 bits. In the description of [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) I see that `rlim_cur` has the type `rlim_t`. So it seems natural to use this 64-bit type:

```
... = (rlim_t)20*1024*1024*1024
```