# segmentation fault with array of string from file

Tags: c

I think I get understand how string works, but some how get a segmentation error when try to run this. I'm trying to create array of string that i read from file f. Also any comments for optimisation and or a better way to code (especially using pointer)is appreciated.

```
char a[700000][120];
char str[120];
int i=0,l,p;
while (fgets(str,120,f)) {
    strcpy(a[i],str);
    i++;
    }
int n=i;
for (i=0;i<=3;i++) {
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think that StackOverflow occured, due to crazy size of first array `a`, use dynamic memory instead.

Comment: Gotta love stack overflow on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is 700000 * 120 too big? That should be <100 MB.

Comment: I realy have a file with near 700000 lines with near 100 char in each line, that I need to sort by string length .

Comment: Then you need allocate the array with `malloc`.

Comment: how do you know that no line is more than 120 chars? how many loops does it get through before seg fault? maybe you should print some debug as it loops through the fgets?

Comment: it is just a strings with long numbers, and the file size is really huge

Comment: well because I wrote this lines ))) and I know that there is no lines more than 120 chars.

Comment: and it get me fault even not starting thee loop

Comment: you mean at a[700000][120]?

Comment: yep, i think I will need to do malloc, but do I need malloc to array Or to the string that I will add?

Comment: Can you think of a good reason you don't just `fgets` directly into the allocated memory (which would also have been appropriate for your posted sample were it not for that oversized `a` array). In other words, `str` is pointless.

Comment: The problem is not the strings (fgets reads size-1 max then adds the zero), it's definitely the stack size limit. 100MB is a lot in a stack!

Comment: write `static` before `char a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
char **a;
int i;

a = malloc(700000 * sizeof(char*));
for (i = 0; i < 700000; i++) {
    a[i] = malloc(120*sizeof(char));
}

// read file here instead
strcpy(a[0],"hello");
strcpy(a[1],"goodbye");
strcpy(a[2],"yes");

for (i=0;i<=3;i++) {
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
}
```

Per Michi, remember to free the memory afterwards.

```
for (i = 0; i < 700000; i++) {
    free(a[i]);
}
free(a);
```

**Appendix** Turns out you can check the stack size AND change it. Consider this

```
struct rlimit rl;
int result;

result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);

printf("stack limit %d\n", rl.rlim_cur);
printf("stack limit %d\n", rl.rlim_max);
return 0;
```

It gives me

```
stack limit 8388608
stack limit -1
```

(there is the 8MB).

Comment: You should call free or at least to mention about the leak

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of array allocation, the size u are trying causes **stack overflow** of the function, because your array can't fit into the memory allocated to the function **stack**.

There is a limit of **8MB** on the maximum size of objects, due to internal compiler implementation limits.
You should use **malloc()** to create large arrays instead.

Comment: does the max size of objects depend on the compiler? or is it always 8 MB?

Comment: apparently you can set the stack size programmatically - I had no idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com/2284691#2284691

Comment: The stack size as far as I know is platform independent and of course there is a default stack size. Could you show me some reference where says that the default one is 8MB?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of creating **str** variable, you could have used the **a** itself. Moreover as mentioned in the comments too, try using dynamic memory, as most programmers don't use stack for huge allocations. May be heap may have greater size than stack.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Environment, ulimit -s can return the stack size.

```
root@ubuntu:# ulimit -s
8192
```

It means the max stack space that the system support is **8192 KB**, that is **8MB**. test program as follows, try to modify array size from 8*1024 to 7*1024.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void test()
{
}

int main()
{
    char a[7*1024][1024];
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("read.txt", "rb");
    if(fp == NULL)
        printf("failure\n");
    else
        printf("success\n");

    char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
        fputs(buffer, stderr);

}
```