# Memset segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, memset

I have got a segmentation fault after initializing a 2d array. I did some research but I have no clue how to fix this, can someone help me out?

The max length of my array is 10000 and **must**  be set by variable length.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    //Set dimension of matrices  
    int length = 10000;
    double matrix1[length][length]; 


    //This line ends up in segmentation fault.  
    memset( matrix1, 0, length*length*sizeof(double));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `matrix2` and why do the datatypes in the definition and `memset` differ?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo in this code example. I still have the issue tho. Thanks for the note :)

Comment: Wow `10000 * 10000 * 8 = 800,000,000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern C compilers allocate local variables on the stack, which has a finite size. Your variable `double matrix1[length][length]` is too large to fit, which causes stack overflow and results in segmentation fault. (Yes, you get segfault even *before* the call to `memset`.)  Either make `matrix1` a global variable or use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc`. In fact, if you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, there will be no need for `memset`.

One more option is to [change the default stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com).

Comment: Specifically, a matrix of type `double[10000][10000]` is roughly 800 MB. A typical stack size is 8 MB.

Comment: Gotcha, thank. I made it work with:     double *matrix1 = (double *)malloc(length*length*sizeof(double));