# Increasing the stack size in C++ when using Cygwin or MinGW in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, stack, cygwin, mingw

I am executing a c++ program with large number of recursion function calls. When executing normally it gives stack overflow on runtime. So I am trying to find a way to increase the stack size. I found two methods: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com) is running but the second if doesn't become true. second method is using the following command while compiling : `g++ -std=c++11 -Wl --stack <stack size> file.c -o file`. This command gives error that  is not a valid file. So what is the way to increase the stack size. And why are the methods I used not working? And for those asking for code, the code is irrelevant. Its just recursive quicksort with large array of 100k ints.

Comment: You omitted commas: -Wl,--stack,900000000    The stack command is passed to link.exe; it must be seen as a single one.

Comment: @tim18 I tried that. It gives error "Missing argument in parameter list" at the "," after -Wl