# Copy-Program works for small files, gives segmentation fault on lager files

Tags: c

To learn some low level C magic, I tried to implement different methods to copy the content of one file to another.

The following method uses a buffer, where I save chunks of data, e.g. 512 bytes. Then I write FROM this buffer into my destination file. Allegedly this is more efficient than copying the whole file directly.

When I use a small buffer, e.g. 512 Bytes, this works fine. 
If I use a big buffer, e.g. 10000000 Bytes, roughly 10MB, I get a segmentation fault.

I am running on Ubuntu.
I tried stuff with `malloc`, but nothing really seams to work for me. I guess the fix will be easy, once I know it.

According to my debbuger the error is in this line:

```
if (stat(to, &statBuffer) == -1)
```

I left in a lot of the error checking I am doing.
Here is the code I run:

```
void copyUsingBuffer(char from[], char to[], long unsigned int bufferSize)
{
    struct stat statBuffer;
    int sourceFD, destFD;
    char buffer[bufferSize / sizeof(char)];
    int EndOfFileErreicht = 0;

    // Dateien pruefen
    if (stat(to, &statBuffer) == -1)
    {
        if (errno != ENOENT)
        {
            perror("Fehler beim Pruefen der Zieldatei");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!(S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode)))
        {
            printf("Die Zieldatei ist keine regulaere Datei\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // Dateien oeffnen
    sourceFD = open(from, O_RDONLY);
    if (sourceFD == -1)
    {
        perror("Fehler beim Oeffnen der Quelldatei");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fstat(sourceFD, &statBuffer) == -1)
    {
        perror("Fehler beim Pruefen der Quelldatei");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (!(S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode)))
    {
        printf("Die Quelldatei ist keine regulaere Datei\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    destFD = open(to, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, statBuffer.st_mode);
    if (destFD == -1)
    {
        perror("Fehler beim Oeffnen der Zieldatei");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (EndOfFileErreicht == 0)
    {
        int geleseneBytes = read(sourceFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (geleseneBytes == -1)
        {
            perror("Fehler beim Lesen aus der Quelldatei");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (geleseneBytes < bufferSize)
        {
            // EOF wurde erreicht, also Flag setzen
            EndOfFileErreicht = 1;
        }


        if (write(destFD, buffer, geleseneBytes) == -1)
        {
            perror("Fehler beim Schreiben in die Zieldatei");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    close(sourceFD);
    close(destFD);
}
```

I would expect that if I enter a 500MB text file, that my program copies this file to its destination.

I realise that there are different ways to implement file copying. I already implemented some of those. In this case I am restricted to using write, read, and the buffer. Also bufferSize NEEDS to be a variable.
The naive way i have using malloc would be:

```
 char* buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
```

But when i use this the file will be corrupted.

Comment: `char buffer[bufferSize / sizeof(char)];` - how much stack space do you think you have?

Comment: On a side note, I am not sure why people are saying this questions lacks MCVE. In my view, it does have correct MCVE.

Comment: You should wait till `read()` returns 0 before assuming you're at the end of the file.

Comment: Are you exceeding your stack size limit?

Comment: Is there a way for me to check how much stack space i have? i have 16GM of ram.

Comment: I would use `malloc` instead of a VLA.

Comment: Stack space is generally very short. On a typical desktop PC you should expect only 1 MB to 10 MB of stack no matter how much RAM your system has. In other words, take @JohnnyMopp 's advice about using `malloc`

Comment: Is there a way for me to increase my stack space? So i can check if the problem really is that the file is too large?

Comment: `bufferSize / sizeof(char)`... `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, so that division is pointless. And, yes, unless `bufferSize` is always going to be a fairly small value, you'll probably want to use `malloc()` instead of a VLA.

Comment: It is not the file that is too large, it is `bufferSize` that is most likely too big.

Comment: @Regicide `ulimit -a` will tell you how much stack space a program can use. You can try increasing it too.

Comment: Setting the stack size is an implementation detail. It changes from compiler to compiler. Heck, C++ doesn't even require the system to have a stack. The language is specified such that if you can find a way to do it, you can use hamster wheels.

Comment: Assuming a gcc compiler because of Ububntu, so [Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com) probably applies. Since you don't know how much stack you need when compiling, `malloc` is still the better option.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you are going to allocate as much memory as the file size, you will end up in trouble sooner or later. You need to allocate fixed buffer size, and than reuse this buffer for multiple reads.

Comment: Im currently working to see if its a stack related problem. @user4581301 how would i solve this correctly with malloc? i tried a few things using it but i got the same errors all the time

Comment: When you used `malloc` did you remember to `free` your buffer when you were done with it?

Comment: Yes i did free the buffer. Also: Currently it is a stack-problem. When i give a extremely high max stack size, i tried 10GB, the programm works. Obviously thats not an ideal solution then.

Comment: All you are doing is reading file X and writing the contents to file y, yes? You can read and write smaller chunks. There should be no reason you can't do this reading the file, say, 4kb at a time, writing the same 4 kb and then looping back around to get another 4k. You don't even need to know the file size with this approach, when you can't read any more data from the source file, you're done.

Comment: i am limited by the fact that the user is supposed to be able to enter the buffersize. Thats the reason it is a variable at all. So if i enter that the buffer should be 10MB big, it has to be 10MB big. So what i wouldwant to  be able to do is create, with malloc, an array, thats as big as the variable "bufferSize"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, after trying a few things.
I replace

```
char buffer[bufferSize / sizeof(char)];
```

with

```
char* buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
```

Using malloc was already suggested. MY mistake was that i didnt replace

```
int geleseneBytes = read(sourceFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Making those changes my program works for all file-sizes.
Thanks for the help everybody!

```
int geleseneBytes = read(sourceFD, buffer, bufferSize);
```

Comment: If you do that, make sure you use `free(buffer);` before the function returns. Otherwise, your program will have a memory leak every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also change the line:

```
int geleseneBytes = read(sourceFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

To:
    int geleseneBytes = read(sourceFD, buffer, bufferSize);
```

Because the sizeof(buffer) is the size of a pointer, not the size of what it points to.   Since you are malloc()ing it, you need to provide this.

ps:

char  buffer[bufferSize/sizeof(char)];

is a bit cring inducing.   Sizeof(char) is 1.

Comment: I already edited this in my answer, i just hit Enter too fast. Thanks nonetheless. Well, i guess we all did cringe-inducing errors at some point. The important thing is to not repeat them i guess. :)

Answer (score -1):

> If someone has a better solution, e.g. something with malloc, it would also be a big help.

#### Option 1:

Don't make `bufferSize` an input to the function. Use a hard-coded size that you know will
not cause buffer overflow, such as [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits).

#### Option 2:

Use `std::vector` insteady of an array.

```
// char buffer[bufferSize / sizeof(char)];
std::vector<char> buffer(bufferSize);
```

Then use `buffer.data()` when you need to access the data of the object.

#### Update (since C++ tag was removed)

Don't make `bufferSize` an input to the function. Use a hard-coded size that you know willnot cause buffer overflow, such as `USHORT_MAX`.

```
void copyUsingBuffer(char from[], char to[])
{
    int bufferSize = USHORT_MAX
    char buffer[USHORT_MAX];

    struct stat statBuffer;
    int sourceFD, destFD;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:c]

Comment: Option 1 is not possible, as it is a requirement for bufferSize to be a variable. Option 2 is not possible, as vectors arent in c. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Now it is tagged C. I found it the same way R Sahu did: It WAS tagged C++. If you're monitoring SO for new C++ questions, it shows up. If you didn't notice the tag was removed... Well, you probably give a C++ answer.